# How to set min start date for Highcharts plot?

Tags: date, charts, highcharts

I have data from 10/19 to 11/01 and I am plotting it using a scattered Highcharts plot (v4.1.10, cannot upgrade). For some reason my x-axis is showing 10/18, but I want it to start with 10/19. I tried using `pointStart`, but this did not work. Any suggestions on how to get the correct starting date to show in my x-axis?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0.5,
  gridLineColor: '#D6D6D6',
  tickInterval: 5,
  dashStyle: 'LongDash',
  lineColor: '#D6D6D6'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%m/%d',
      week: '%d/%b',
      month: '%b/%y',
      year: '%Y'
    },
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: 'date'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: '#D6D6D6',
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    startOnTick: true
},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      marker: {
        radius: 5,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true,
            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
          }
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: this.toolTip
    }
},
chart: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginRight: 0,
    reflow: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
    },
    type: 'scatter',
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) 
        + ' - ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        return s;
    },
},
series: values
});
```

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/thehme/dwnx6o8e/)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the x axis `min` value:

```
xAxis: {
    min:1539950400000
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/dwnx6o8e/9/

Depending on the data and other options, you may need to look at other properties, like `startOnTick`, `tickInterval`, etc.

Comment: using `moment.utc("10/19/2018").valueOf()` as the value for `min` does not seem to help, even though this would be the beginning of 10/19/2018. `startOnTick: true` is the current value being used, so I would expect this to be enough, but it is not.

Comment: @jlbriggs is right, check this demo where I changed tickInterval: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dwnx6o8e/17/. If this is not enough, you can always use `xAxis.tickPositions` property and provide array of precise tick positions. See: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: @thehme if anything, under certain circumstances, you may need to set `startOnTIck: false` in order to make it work right. That aside, I would not use 00:00:00 on 10/18, as that will, specifically, push the axis back far enough to use 10/18 as the start. I would use 12:00:00, which is what I did in my example. You may also be able to play with the x axis `minPadding` and still use 00:00:00, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @jlbriggs, I am going to play around with these settings and report back, in case it helps anyone else

Comment: I think that not using `min`, removing `startOnTick` and using the `tickInterval` makes the latest data set plot as expected with the correct x-axis, so I am going to see if these changes work in my code, because they seem to work in the jsfiffle http://jsfiddle.net/thehme/dwnx6o8e/

Comment: thanks @WojciechChmiel your first exampled using `tickInterval` seems to work for my latest data set, so will check if it works in my real code